# How do I put a count function on my SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-list

How do I see the total amount of items I have in my SharePoint List? preferably on the view screen.

Comment: While the goals of the duplicate-nominated questions are the same, this question doesn't necessarily prefer a C# implementation. Therefore I don't see the questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

On the List View where you want to show Item Count:

1. Edit The List View
2. Scroll down to Totals Section
3. Change the drope down value for Column Name(For which count needs to be shown) to Count
   [image]
4. Click Ok.
5. It will show Count under the Column
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Any idea why these steps would not result in a count being added? I've followed these steps exactly & the cursor spins and the page refreshes but a count is not added to the column and doesn't display. When reviewing the drop down to try again, the check-mark re-appears as 'None' instead of count. I've tried these steps several times within multiple different views and on multiple columns and the count will not display. Help!

Comment: Note, I am an owner on the site so it is not a permissions issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/125410)